# Backbone.js and Require.js issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, mvvm

I am trying to convert an existing Backbone.js project into Require.js.

As recommended I am modularising my components. My router is the starting point in the application, thus my main.js require file looks like this:

```
requirejs.config({

    'baseUrl': '/',

    'paths': {
        'app': 'app',
        // define vendor paths
        'jquery'        :   'bower_components/jquery/jquery',
        'underscore'    :   'bower_components/underscore/underscore',
        'backbone'      :   'bower_components/backbone/backbone',
        'handlebars'    :   'bower_components/handlebars/handlebars',
        'nprogress'     :   'bower_components/nprogress/nprogress',
    },

    'shim':{
        'jquery': {
            'exports': '$'
        },

        'underscore': {
            'exports': '_'
        },

        'backbone': {
            'deps': ['jquery', 'underscore'],
            'exports': 'Backbone'
        },

        'handlebars': {
            'exports': 'Handlebars'
        }

    }


});

require(['app/js/routes/router'], function(Router) {
    // Fire up the quattro
});
```

My router then looks like this

```
define(['backbone', '/app/js/views/HomepageView'], function(Backbone) {

    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            "": "showHomepage",
            "categories/:sofa": "showCategoryList",
            "range/:categoryName/:sofaName": "showProductRange",
            "customersearch/:customerName": "showCustomerSearch"
        }
    });

    // Initialise our router
    var router = new AppRouter;

    router.on("route:showHomepage", function(param){
        localStorage.removeItem('lastProduct');
        var homepageview = new HomepageView({ el: $('#content') });
    })

    // Start the router
    Backbone.history.start();

});
```

However when I navigate to my route '/' for HomepageView to initialise, I get the following error no matter what I try and I cannot seem to find the solution..

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined HomepageView.js:1
```

Answer (score 0):

changing the first line to the following would be a start.

define(['backbone', '/app/js/views/HomepageView'], function(Backbone, HomePageView) {

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault, however it doesn't fix the issue.